# Why am I updating GNOME Application Platform on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

Kubuntu runs KDE, not GNOME, right? So why does Discover want me to update to GNOME Application Platform version 3.38?

Comment: Please provide more context and the complete, exact message.

Comment: Gnome is not just a desktop environment but also a GUI framework. When people develop software (eg. Google Chrome, Gimp, Inkscape, LibreOffice etc.) they usually need to choose a GUI framework to write their GUI application. Unlike Windows and Mac OS, Linux does not have a "default" GUI framework (called toolkits). There are a lot of different toolkits available for people to use to build GUI programs including GTK (Gnome's toolkit) and Qt (KDE's toolkit). Once a developer chooses a toolkit he will often never rewrite his application to use another toolkit because it is a lot of work.

Comment: Note that both GTK and Qt are also available on Windows and Mac OS. So even on Windows and Mac OS you will find a lot of people having bits of Gnome and KDE installed (mostly libraries) because they use software that depend on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've provided no specifics as to what release of Kubuntu, nor clues as to packages so I'll make assumptions.

A view of Kubuntu 22.10 manifest shows a GNOME 3.38 snap package which is used by the `firefox` snap, ie. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu//releases/22.10/release/kubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.manifest shows

```
snap:gnome-3-38-2004    stable/ubuntu-22.10 119
```

That is **not** a *deb* package, but is used by the `firefox` (*and potentially other snap packages you may add to your system, but are none are included with Kubuntu by default*) *snap* package.

That file is GNOME 3.38 required because `firefox` uses GNOME 3.38 components.

If you meant another package, you didn't specifically mention any like you didn't mention any release, thus I used the current *latest* 22.10 & default packages as example.

For more details you can view https://snapcraft.io/install/gnome-3-38-2004/ubuntu

FYI:  The 20.04 reference is because currently that package was *built* on a 20.04 system, but will run on all releases from 16/16.04 through to 22/22.10/22.04

Comment: The *manifest* link I provided shows what is included on the ISO (ie. I grabbed Kubuntu 22.10 manifest as no release was specified or the *latest* released).  The *manifest* being an easy means to see what's included on installation media though actual installs may contain all/less than that depending on options selected and hardware used during installation for some ISOs